# ¿Cómo crear varios archivos en una subcarpeta?

Tags: linux, bash

¿Cómo se crea más de un archivo en una subcarpeta sin ingresar a la carpeta?

Ahora utilizo:

```
touch subcarperta/archivo.txt
```

Pero cuando quiero crear otro tengo que escribir el otra vez la ruta donde quiero mi archivo.
El tema es que quiero crear mas de dos archivos en esa ruta sin tener que escribirla constantemente

Algo así como:

```
touch subcarperta/ archivo.txt otroArchivo.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la sintaxis `{}` para que los elementos se desplieguen automáticamente:

```
touch carpeta/{fichero1,fichero2,fichero3}
```

Automáticamente Bash lo traducirá a:

```
touch carpeta/fichero1 carpeta/fichero2 carpeta/fichero3
```

Esta es la funcionalidad [*brace expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) (expansión de llaves) de Bash que resulta muy útil para generar contenido automáticamente utilizando rangos de números o letras:

```
$ echo {1..5}
1 2 3 4 5

$ echo hola{1,2,3,4,5}
hola1 hola2 hola3 hola4 hola5

$ echo letra{A..F}
letraA letraB letraC letraD letraE letraF
```

Nótese además que esta expansión de llaves se puede combinar para provocar el efecto de producto cartesiano:

```
# imprime todas las combinaciones de 201X/Y, con X en 5, ..., 7 e Y en 1, ..., 5
$ echo 201{5..7}/{1..5}  
2015/1 2015/2 2015/3 2015/4 2015/5 2016/1 2016/2 2016/3 2016/4 2016/5 2017/1 2017/2 2017/3 2017/4 2017/5
```

Siguiendo el enlace de arriba podemos leer la descripción (traducción mía):

> Una expresión secuencia es de la forma `{x..y[..incr]}`, donde `x` e `y` son o bien números enteros o bien caracteres simples, e `incr`, un incremento opcional, es un íntegro.
>
> Cuando se pasan enteros, la expresión se expande a todo número entre `x` e `y`, inclusivamente. Los enteros proporcionados pueden prefijarse con '0' para forzar que cada elemento tenga el mismo tamaño.
>    cuando `x` o `y` empieza con un cero, la shell intenta forzar que todos los elementos generados contengan el mismo número de dígitos, añadiendo ceros cuando sea necesario.
>
> Cuando se proporcionan caracteres, la expresión se expande a cada carácter entre `x` e `y` alfabéticamente, inclusivo, usando el locale de C.
>
> Nótese que tanto `x` como `y` deben ser del mismo tipo. Cuando el incremento se proporciona, se usa como diferencia entre cada elemento. El incremento por defecto es 1 o -1 según el caso.

Answer (score 2):

Cómo @josego ha comentado podrias hacer un ciclo for para iterar en una lista de parametros los cuáles serian los archivos a crear en el directorio o subcarpeta, el script seria el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Tú directorio.
dir=workspace

for i in $@; do
  touch ${dir}/$i
done
```

La variable `$@` contiene los parametros pasados al script separados por espacios.

Solo quedaria asignarle al script permisos de ejecución y moverlo a un directorio que se encuentre en la variable `$PATH` si deseas usarlo en cualquier lugar. Puedes nombrar al escript cómo tu quieras teniendo en cuenta los comandos internos de la shell bash por ejemplo podrias llamarle `touchs` y podrias usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
touchs file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

> la shell bash tiene preferencia entre sus simbolos la orden en el que se ejecutan es:
>
> 1. Alias
> 2. Palabras claves (for, if, while, etc.)
> 3. Funciones
> 4. Comandos internos (cd, type, rm, etc.)
> 5. Scripts y programas ejecutables.

Si tienes creado un alias llamado `touchs` se ejecutaria el alias en lugar del scripts por la orden de preferencia así que cuidado con esté aspecto.

Answer (score 1):

Pues Lo mejor es que crees una variable con la ruta de la carpeta y luego simplemente la concatenar con el nombre del archivo.

Vamos al codigo.

```
ruta="workspace"
touch ${ruta}/hola.txt
```

Saludos

Comment: lo que quiero es crear dos o más archivos eso me soluciona cuando escribo una ruta muy larga y no quiero repetirla, pero hay alguna forma de escribirla solo una vez?

Answer (score 0):

Si queres agregar muchos archivos podes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
ruta_larga="ruta_larga"
touch ${ruta_larga}/hola.txt ${ruta_larga}/otroArchivo.txt ${ruta_larga}/otroArchivo1.txt ${ruta_larga}/otroArchivo1.txt
```

O si no hace un script en bash que tenga un for y un listado de los nombres de los archivos.